# CallKit without VOIP

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, callkit

Please let me clear, is it possible to integrate CallKit without using VOIP?

What I want to achieve is to get call history from iPhone. and I know it is not possible. So I want to create my own history with the help of CallKit. For this  purpose I need following:

1. I want to detect incoming call (not voip)
2. Outgoing call (not voip)
3. In all states - background, foreground, not running, suspended
4. Call duration

Can we do this with the help of CallKit or is there any other workaround?

**Note: It is not about VOIP Apps**

Comment: No. You cannot get any call details. It a breach of user privacy

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to integrate CallKit without using VOIP?

I would say yes, SpeakerBox (the Apple CallKit example) doesn't use VoIP.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Speakerbox/Listings/Speakerbox_SpeakerboxCall_swift.html

is it possible to integrate CallKit in all states - background, foreground, not running, suspended without using VOIP?

No, if the app is suspended or not running you can't detect an incoming call.

Answer (score 0):

For case of `CallDuration` in active mode can be traceable by using callkit. Let me know, if you are only interested to know `Call Duration`. I can give full detail.

Other all cases that you mentioned are not possible to trace, unless your phone is jailbroken.

Comment: Hi mehul thakkar. I want to get the call duaratio only..Can you give me the code samples?